# How to access individual's structure in GPLearn fitness function?

Tags: genetic-programming, gplearn

I'm trying to implement a variation of the Iterative Structure-Based Algorithm (ISBA) concept to create a structure-based GP in GPLearn. Specifically, I'm trying to implement a penalty for excessive similarity to past populations in the fitness function, by calculating the relative distance between the current program's structure and saved past structures. However, to do this, I need to be able to access the individual whose fitness is being evaluated in my custom fitness function. Said custom fitness function is being implemented in accordance with the [documentation](https://gplearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced.html). Is there any way to get a representation of the individual from GPLearn in a custom fitness function?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Update: upon further research, I found a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/trevorstephens/gplearn/issues/281) mentioning a similar situation. Unfortunately, it seems that getting the formula expression of each individual is not supported as of the 24th of November 2022, making using GPLearn as a library impossible for this particular structure-based GP implementation.